# Update row status using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am currently trying to program my first ajax interface using Rails.

The application currently shows a table populated with list items. The user has to approve or reject each of the list items. I currently have an edit link at the end of each row that shows a form in which I can approve the list item.

I am thinking on using a checkbox instead of the edit link. When the user clicks the checkbox I want to update the database with the status, user name and date/time without leaving this page.

1. What steps should I follow?
2. Can I use a checkbox or am I
   restricted to buttons?
3. What xxx_remote helper should I use?
4. How can I update the checkbox state with the results of the ajax call?

Comment: You can also directly edit your own question, no need to put additions into the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that a checkbox is the correct control for what you're looking for.
You said you want user's to be able to approve or reject items which means that you have 3 states: unhandled, approved and rejected. A checkbox only supports 2 states: off and on

I would use two links accept and reject and then do it as follows.

**In your view:**

```
...
<tr id="item1">
  <td>Accept or Reject</td>
  <td>
    link_to_remote 'accept', :action => :accept, :id => 1, :method => :post
    link_to_remote 'reject', :action => :reject, :id => 1, :method => :post
  </td>
</tr>
...
```

**In your controller**

```
def accept
  item = Item.find(params[:id])
  item.accept
  respond_to do |want|
    want.js {
      render :update do |page|
        page << "$('item_#{item.id}').cells[0].innerHTML = 'Accepted'"
        ...include other updates you need to make to your row...
        page.visual_effect :highlight, "item_#{item.id}"
      end
    }
  end
end    
... similar for reject method ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment to solution proposed by Andrew,

I had to write params of `link_to_remote` function like this

```
link_to_remote 'reject', :url => {:action => :reject, :id => item.id, :method => :post}
```

Also, remember to add new actions to your routes.rb if You are using restful resources
i.e.

```
map.resources :items, :member => {:accept => :post, :reject => :post}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the new actions too.